# Very strange session issue with Opencart and PHP

Tags: php, session, opencart, session-variables, session-cookies

I've posted this on Opencart forums however no one could probably figure out what the problem was.

Running Opencart 1.5.6.4. PHP-5.4.42

If a user X is logged in on the website, if another user visits the site he also gets logged in from X's account automatically. I've witnessed this myself, when i was browsing and it showed me as logged in as a customer who lives 500 miles away! If the user X, has something added in his cart it would show up as well.

So, since I'm logged in through that account, I can do whatever I like from that account, place an order, modify details etc. Scary! This entire problem has been aggravated with increase in traffic to my website.

I've tried moving the save.session_path to a different folder /tmp altogether, but it hasn't helped.

I'm not a full time dev, so kinda having troubles figuring out what the problem is. Would be great if somebody can help.

php.ini has the following session related entries

```
session.save_path = /webroot/sitename/tmp/
session.use_only_cookies = 1;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = 1;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
```

session.php

```
class Session {
    public $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        if (!session_id()) {
            ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'On');
            ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
            ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
           session_start();
        }

        $this->data =& $_SESSION;
    }

    function getId() {
        return session_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: we'll need to see all of your settings such as save.session_path, and the code that handles your logins and cookies.

Comment: Have you got any page caching enabled?

Comment: @Barett- have added relevant code. not sure which files handle the cookies and login. Let me know so I can post relevant code.

Comment: @JayGilford Yes, page caching is enabled.

Comment: Then I would hazard a guess it's not being disabled when a customer is logged in

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to some customers without an email (simplified registration form). Opencart was confused. Solutions:

First update customers with random email (note that email is not used to reach customers):

```
update `oc_customer` set email = concat(LEFT(UUID(), 8), '@example.com') where email = '';
```

Then update the registration form to generate random email at registration to avoid this situation in the future.

Disclaimer: I had access to the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this solution will help any users facing it on Opencart.

The specific problem is related to Page Caching. If there is a page caching plugin please make sure it is disabled on Account & checkout pages. The result was cached account pages ended up getting served to multiple users.

Contrary to solutions I've come across to the same question elsewhere, it has nothing to do session storage and shared hosting - I faced this issue on a VPS where session storage could not be shared.